# What should an academic disclosure statement look like

Tags: journals, paper-submission, writing, writing-style

Nowadays journals require people to disclose conflicts of interest by submitting a disclosure statement. I wonder how this statement should be written.  I found a lot of examples of disclosure statements online, but they are all from some business environment not academia.

Does an academic disclosure statement for a journal follow some special guidelines? Does anyone have an example of a disclosure statement for journal publication?

Comment: How do the statements look in the particular journal?